# OpenAPITools / openapi-generator how to disable generating the service.go code

Tags: openapi, openapi-generator

I am using docker to generate the go api code but how do I pass the -Dnoservice to the docker container

```
docker run --rm -v "${PWD}:/local" openapitools/openapi-generator-cli generate \
    -i https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openapitools/openapi-generator/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/test/resources/3_0/petstore.yaml \
    -g go-server \
    -o /local/out/go
```

referring to https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/go-server
where it says

> Generates a Go server library using OpenAPI-Generator. By default, it
> will also generate service classes -- which you can disable with the
> -Dnoservice environment variable.

Comment: I think it's meant to say "command-line argument" instead of "environment variable". Try appending `-Dnoservice` to your command and see if it works.

Comment: Came back with an error if run with docker run --rm -v "${PWD}:/local" openapitools/openapi-generator-cli generat ....-Dnoservice : [error] Found unexpected parameters: [-Dnoservice]

Comment: I think `-D` was replaced with `-p`, according to https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/commit/a96ab1cf9d1528e11b815fea020e4f4290591297. I didn't get an error when running `-p noservice`.